# Excel if isnumber search

Tags: excel, if-statement, search, time

[updating picture solved issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxZmw.png)
I'm trying to check cell IF contains a string "Friday" AND the hour is bigger/later then 17:00 THEN multiply the hour rate by 1.5
I'm using this func:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Saturday",$A$3:$A$33)),$C$40*((C45-B45)*24)*1.5,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Friday",$A$3:$A$33)),IF("Friday",A42:A71,IF(TIME(17,0,0),$C$40*((C45-B45)*24)*1.5,$C$40*((C45-B45)*24)))))
```

in short explain is: Everything multyply by $C$40 (25$) except of Friday after 17:00 that its multiply $C$40 *1.5

But it's not working for me. Can somebody help?

```
        NAME    HOUR RATE $     
DATE    dany    25  TOTAL PAY/DAY   
    start work at.. worked until..      
Sunday  07:30   16:00   212.50  
Monday  07:30   16:00   212.50  
Tuesday 07:30   16:00   212.50  
Wednesday   15:01   16:00   24.58   
Thursday    07:00   16:00   225.00  
Friday  17:01   23:30   162.08  
Saturday    17:30   22:00   112.50  
Sunday  07:30   16:00   212.50  
Monday  07:30   16:00   212.50  
Tuesday 07:30   16:00   212.50  
Wednesday   08:00   15:00   175.00  
Thursday    07:30   16:00   212.50  
Friday  07:30   16:00   212.50  
Saturday    18:00   22:45   118.75  
Sunday  07:30   16:00   212.50  
Monday  07:30   16:00   212.50  
Tuesday 07:30   16:00   212.50  
Wednesday   07:30   16:00   212.50  
Thursday    07:30   16:00   212.50  
Friday  07:30   16:00   212.50  
Saturday    07:30   16:00   212.50  
Sunday  07:30   16:00   212.50  
Monday  07:30   16:00   212.50  
Tuesday 07:30   16:00   212.50  
Wednesday   07:30   16:00   212.50  
Thursday    07:30   16:00   212.50  
Friday  07:30   16:00   212.50  
Saturday    07:30   16:00   212.50  
Sunday  07:30   16:00   212.50  
Monday  07:30   16:00   212.50  
TOTAL HOURES        236.72      
TOTAL SALERY            5,917.92
```

[image]

Comment: WHY DOWNGRADE - if you can help -good! if not ...

Comment: Show a small sample of the starting data, and then an example of the desired result.

Comment: i edit my quetion - its not so clear - is ther any way to upload the table well?  as well - cheack up the picture - thanks

Comment: It looks to me that you want all of Saturday to be paid at 1.5 times normal. So if a person works 10 hours they should get $375. Is that true?

Comment: Now for Friday. If they work 2 hours, from 16:00 until 18:00, do they get ( $25 + $25 ), - OR -  $25 + ($25 * 1.5) - OR - ($25 + $25) * 1.5 ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, Try this:

```
=IF(A42="Friday",IF(C42-TIMEVALUE("17:00")<0,(((C42-B42)*24)*$C$40),IF(TIMEVALUE("17:00")-B42<0,(((C42-B42)*24)*$C$40)*1.5,(((C42-B42)-(C42-TIMEVALUE("17:00")))*24)*$C$40+((C42-TIMEVALUE("17:00"))*24)*$C$40*1.5)),IF(A42="Saturday",(((C42-B42)*24)*$C$40)*1.5,(((C42-B42)*24)*$C$40)))
```

It looks like your data is starting in row 42.

The formula first checks to see if the day is Friday, if it is not then it checks for Saturday . If it is Saturday it does the time and a half calculation. If not Saturday then it must be one of the other days and does the straight time calculation.

Most of this formula is concerned with figuring out when the person worked on Friday. I think it would be a good idea if you can add extra columns to your spreadsheet to do some of the Friday calculations there. For example add a column that show total hours worked that day, and another column that shows the overtime hours for that day.

Comment: Check my comment on your question. I had a question about the hour.

Comment: ow - yes friend thanks - If the employe start work at friday at 16:00 until 22:00, So 16:00 until 17:00 its a normal rate of 25$ per hour and from 17:00 until 22:00 its a 25*1.5 !  thanks

Comment: by the way im using IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH ... becous i use full date in my table - Friday, november 11 , 2016 (i just use it in hebrew יום שישי, 11 בנובמבר 2016 - and for some reson i cannot translate the full date in my Google Sheet

Comment: Try asking the Google Sheet Hebrew date translation as a new question. Most likely you'll be able to adapt that answer into the formula that we are building here.

Comment: I SOLVED 50% of my issue - now friday is 25*1.5 after 17:00                           =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Saturday",$A$42:$A$71)),$C$40*((C47-B47)*24)*1.5,IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Friday",$A$42:$A$71,$B$42:$B$71>TIME(17,0,0))),$C$40*((C47-B47)*24)*1.5,$C$40*((C47-B47)*24)))

Comment: now we need to solve the issue - IF the employe working on friday from 16:00 to 22:00 and the first hour 16-17 is 25/hour and from 17:00 to 22:00 is 25*1.5

Comment: I've updated my answer, it should have what you need. I also added a suggestion to add more columns. That would allow you to have a simpler formula.

Comment: There's no need for that. Everything can be taken care of right here where other people might learn something too.

Comment: WORKS LIKE A CHARM

Comment: Good job, I'm happy to have helped.

Comment: By the way - i leastn to your advice and i add some advantage to my table - i add a cell value of the time 17:00 so i replace the TIMEVALUE becouse every month + the friday time is change little bit - so ill be able to change only the value in this particulary cell. thanks a lot - i m keep working upgrading this table - i edit (add more printscreen of the change)

Comment: Houston, we have a problem - i hope you can help me with this:         becous i use the full date (Friday, November 1, 2016) , NOT only the word Friday... So i must use IF(ISNUMBER(FIND...

Comment: I trued this: =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND($A$4:$A$11="Friday",IF(C4-E2<0,(((C4-B4)*24)*$C$2),IF(E2-B4<0,(((C4-B4)*24)*$C$2)*1.5,(((C4-B4)-(C4-E2))*24)*$C$2+((C4-E2)*24)*$C$2*1.5))))),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND($A$4:$A$11="Saturday",(((C4-B4)*24)*$C$2)*1.5,(((C4-B4)*24)*$C$2)))
)       [[[ E2= 17:00:00 (TIMEVALUE)]]]

Comment: This formula is getting too complicated. I highly recommend adding more columns. One for the date (11/24/2016), one for day of week(Thursday),One for hours worked before 17:00, another for hours worked past 17:00. That would help you a lot.

Comment: Succeed!!!           =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Friday",$A$4:$A$11)),IF(C4-$E$2<0,(((C4-B4)*24)*$C$2),IF($E$2-B4<0,(((C4-B4)*24)*$C$2)*1.5,(((C4-B4)-(C4-$E$2))*24)*$C$2+((C4-$E$2)*24)*$C$2*1.5)),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Saturday",$A$4:$A$11)),((C4-B4)*24)*$C$2*1.5,((C4-B4)*24)*$C$2))                 i add new picture - please see - thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Friday",$A$4:$A$11)),IF(C4-$E$2<0,(((C4-B4)*24)*$C$2),IF($E$2-B4<0,(((C4-B4)*24)*$C$2)*1.5,(((C4-B4)-(C4-$E$2))*24)*$C$2+((C4-$E$2)*24)*$C$2*1.5)),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Saturday",$A$4:$A$11)),((C4-B4)*24)*$C$2*1.5,((C4-B4)*24)*$C$2))

[chack image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A2bv.png)